# if (has_custom_menu())?

Tags: theme-development, menus

I've taken this line from header.php of TwentyTen where its loading the custom menus...

```
<?php /* Our navigation menu.  
If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu.  
The menu assiged to the primary position is the one used.  
If none is assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used.  */ ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

I understand their fallback plan, but for mine, if no custom menu has been assigned to my custom menu selector, I don't want to return anything. What's the function to determine if my custom menu has an assigned menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Parameters), you should be able to just pass the fallback_cb parameter as false to have wp_nav_menu return nothing. So something like:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'fallback_cb' => FALSE ) ); ?>
```

Comment: That's it. I found it shortly after I posted. Hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at the [has_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu) conditional tag/function.